# What is the value for "class" when the scope is "markup.foo" in a sublime theme?

Tags: themes, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

I can't figure out what string to use in the element "class" of a theme to assign colors and fonts to a syntax scope.

The plugin "Always Show Scope" shows me that the scope in my file is correct: `text.story.markup.foo`. In the theme, I've added a variable and this rule:

```
    {
        "class": "???what to put here???",
        "foreground": "var(blue)"
    },
```

But neither of these classes makes the text blue:

```
foo
markup.foo
scope.markup.foo
text.story.markup.foo
scope.text.story.markup.foo
```

I can add a typo in the theme file to see an error in the console, so I'm sure I'm editing the right file and ST3 reloads it automatically but other than that, my changes have no effect whatsoever.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you edit the correct file. There is a "theme" and a "**color** theme" file.

The former has the extension `.sublime-theme`, the latter `.sublime-color-theme`.

Also, use `scope` instead of `class`:

```
    {
        "scope": "markup.foo",
        "foreground": "var(blue)"
    }
```

Comment: The name `theme` for this is an unfortunate side effect of the legacy `tmTheme` file format for specifying color schemes. This is an easy trap to fall into. For what it's worth, `tmTheme` files are still suported, but `sublime-color-scheme` files have more features.